# Fixed position sidebar that stays relative to parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a mockup of a little CSS quandary I can't puzzle out (see image).

Basically I have a sidebar (blue) that I want to have position: fixed, but I want this sidebar to respect the parent (red) and always only take up 25% of that parent's width, and never go outside the bounds of the red parent (so red all feels like one big centered element).

If I fix the sidebar, it will jump out of the red container, obviously. If I nest blue in an absolute position container (and give red position: relative) blue will stay fixed but it won't fill the full 25%.

[image]

Comment: Css grid is your friend

Comment: That won't solve the position fixed situation tho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with `position: sticky`? It should stay relative to parent.

Comment: The problem with sticky is that I need the height of the blue area to always be 100% of whats available to it, sticky only works if the blue area is shorter than 100.

Comment: Since parent is in vw can't you just give 23vw to the sidebar? (25% of 92)

Comment: or you can create a css variable called --topbar: 92vw; then do a  calc(var(--topbar) - 75%);